# Tikz: foreach loop ignores part of the edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to draw some more or less advanced grid, using three consecutive (non-nested) foreach loops. For unknown reasons, the third loop seems to be ignored...
Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (22,3) (F) {$F$};

\foreach \i in {0,...,10}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \node at (20-2*\i,4) (A\label) {$v_{\label}$};
}

\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelp}{\i + 1}
    \node at (19-2*\i,2) (E\i) {$u_{\label}$}
    (A\labelp) edge (E\label)
    (E\label) edge (A\label)
    (A\labelp) edge (A\label);
}

\foreach \i in {0,...,8}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelpp}{\i + 2}
    (E\label) edge[bend left = 50] (E\labelpp);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: There is no tikz command in the third loop. Add `\draw` before `(E\label...`. (and lower the upper bound to 7)

Answer (score 2):

Harald already commented that a `\draw` command was missing in third loop. So, next code just want to show a possibility to avoid `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` for computing `labels` based in `index` values.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (22,3) (F) {$F$};

\foreach \i [count=\label from 0] in {0,...,10}
{
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \node at (20-2*\i,4) (A\label) {$v_{\label}$};
}

\foreach \i [count=\label from 0, count=\labelp] in {0,...,9}
{
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelp}{\i + 1}
    \node at (19-2*\i,2) (E\i) {$u_{\label}$}
    (A\labelp) edge (E\label)
    (E\label) edge (A\label)
    (A\labelp) edge (A\label);
}

\foreach \i [count=\label from 0, evaluate=\label as \labelpp using \label+2] in {0,...,7}
{
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
%    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelpp}{\i + 2}
    \draw (E\label) edge[bend left=50] (E\labelpp);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want someting like this?  Set the third `\foreach` loop's bounds to {-1,...,7} and add the `\node` statement:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (22,3) (F) {$F$};
      \foreach \i in {0,...,10}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \node at (20-2*\i,4) (A\label) {$v_{\label}$};
}

\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelp}{\i + 1}
    \node at (19-2*\i,2) (E\i) {$u_{\label}$}
    (A\labelp) edge (E\label)
    (E\label) edge (A\label)
    (A\labelp) edge (A\label);
}

\foreach \i in {-1,...,7}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\label}{\i}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\labelpp}{\i + 2}
    \node at (17-2*\i,2) (E\label) {}
    (E\label) edge[bend left = 50] (E\labelpp);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]